# Service Builder does not compile code that depends on IVY jar

Tags: java, ant, liferay, ivy

I have a basic program with a simple entity for the service builder set up with no properties for the purpose of web service calls. I depend locally on the `javax.ws.rs` library contained in `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar`.

In the IDE, The code does not show any errors. I can see the Ivy dependencies in the project explorer window. however when i call the build-services command, It fails to compile the code with Classes from the external jars.

Am i missing a step when depending on jars in my application? shouldn't this automatically be linked?

ant output:

```
   [javac] Compiling 4 source files to C:\liferay\liferay-developer-studio\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\myApp-portal-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 1. ERROR in C:\liferay\liferay-developer-studio\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\myApp-portal-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\example\myApp\portal\service\ExternalApiLocalService.java (at line 69)
    [javac]     public javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget myAppRestApi();
    [javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] javax.ws.rs.client cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 2. ERROR in C:\liferay\liferay-developer-studio\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\myApp-portal-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\example\myApp\portal\service\ExternalApiLocalService.java (at line 71)
    [javac]     public javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget myAppRegisterService();
    [javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] javax.ws.rs.client cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 3. ERROR in C:\liferay\liferay-developer-studio\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\myApp-portal-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\example\myApp\portal\service\ExternalApiLocalService.java (at line 73)
    [javac]     public javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget myAppValidPaService();
    [javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] javax.ws.rs.client cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 4. ERROR in C:\liferay\liferay-developer-studio\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\myApp-portal-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\example\myApp\portal\service\ExternalApiLocalServiceClp.java (at line 127)
    [javac]     public javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget myAppRestApi() {
    [javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] javax.ws.rs.client cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 5. ERROR in C:\liferay\liferay-developer-studio\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\myApp-portal-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\example\myApp\portal\service\ExternalApiLocalServiceClp.java (at line 146)
    [javac]     return (javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget)ClpSerializer.translateOutput(returnObj);
    [javac]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [javac] javax.ws.rs.client cannot be resolved to a type
    [javac] ----------
    [javac] 6. ERROR in C:\liferay\liferay-developer-studio\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\myApp-portal-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\com\example\myApp\portal\service\ExternalApiLocalServiceClp.java (at line 150)
    [javac]     public javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget myAppRegisterService() {
    [javac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ...........................etc

BUILD FAILED
C:\liferay\liferay-developer-studio\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-plugin.xml:262: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\liferay\liferay-developer-studio\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:634: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

ivy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ivy-module
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
>
    <info module="portlet_liferay_faces_alloy_tmpl" organisation="com.liferay" />

    <dependencies defaultconf="default">
        ...
        <dependency name="jersey-common" org="org.glassfish.jersey.core" rev="2.12" transitive="true" />
        <dependency name="jersey-client" org="org.glassfish.jersey.core" rev="2.12" transitive="true" />
        <dependency name="html-json" org="org.glassfish.jersey.media" rev="2.12" transitive="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Kind regards,
thenaglecode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost answered the question yourself, but it's not quite obvious: When servicebuilder runs, it executes some java code that needs to run with the project's classpath as well: ServiceBuilder will compile/inspect your code in order to generate the appropriate interfaces etc.

For this reason you'll need to inject the project's dependencies to the servicebuilder process as well. When you run servicebuilder from the IDE, it's most likely running the Ant task, which will take all obvious (to ant) dependencies from the webapp (e.g. what it finds in `WEB-INF/lib` and the appserver's global classpath). The Ant process will not scan any ivy, maven or other build tool's dependency declarations - unfortunately you'll have to add this dependency twice.